# Weblogic Server time change

Tags: timezone, weblogic12c

We're having a Weblogic Server on which we tried changing the time zone from current GMT to IST(GMT+5:30). This change led to the log file storing the right time zone.

However, the data displayed in the application too moved by GMT+5:30.

The application is expected to display the data with the time zone in which it was stored.

Are we missing something while changing the time zone of server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is application dependent, you may have to configure the application as well.

In general though, it's not a bad idea to keep servers in GMT no matter where they are located.